# refresh table content . jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using a solution of my previous question to refresh my table after deleting a row. 
it works and refresh my table well. but the style and other linked js doesn't work.
before

[image: before refresh]

after
[image: after refresh]

//index.php

```
    <div id="tableContainer">    
    <?php
        include('table.php');
    ?>
</div>
```

//jquery/ajax

```
   function deleteUser(id,thisObj){
           $.ajax({
             url: 'insert.php',
            type: 'POST',
             data: {'delAdmin':id}, // An object with the key 'submit' and    value 'true;
             success: function (result) {

            $("#tableContainer").html(result);

           }
       }); 
      }
```

//insert.php

```
 /*Delete  admin */ 
if(isset($_POST['delAdmin'])){
 $idval=$_POST['delAdmin'];
 $query="delete from admins where id=$idval";
 $result=mysqli_query($dbCnn,$query) or die("خطا!");
```

}
    include('table.php');

//table.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <!-- jquery ui -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/ui/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
    <script src="js/ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!--activejs-->
    <script src="js/activejs.js"></script>
   <!--include font-awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../fonts/awesome/css/font-    awesome.min.css"/>
     <!-- table paging and sorter -->
    <script type='text/javascript'    src='js/sortpager/dist/js/slimtable.min.js'></script>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='js/sortpager/css/slimtable.css'/>
</head>

 <body>

 <table id="usersListTable" style=" border:1px solid #00CCFF!important;"    class="">
        <thead>
  <tr>
          <th>ردیف</th>
          <th>نام کاربری</th>
          <th>کلمه عبور</th>
          <th>رایانامه</th>
          <th>سطح</th>
          <th>فعال</th>
          <th>آخرین ورود</th>
          <th class="thBgNone"></th>
          <th class="thBgNone"></th>
        </tr>
</thead>
      <tbody id="tb">

      </tbody>
 <?php
            include("db_inc.php");
             $usersQry="select * from admins";
             $usersQryResult=mysqli_query($dbCnn,$usersQry);
              $c=1;
               while($user=mysqli_fetch_array($usersQryResult)){
               echo"
                  <tr>
                      <td>$c<span class='userId' style='display:none'>$user[id]</span></td>
                       <td>$user[user]</td>
                       <td>$user[pass]</td>
                       <td>$user[email]</td>
                       <td>$user[level]</td>
                       <td>$user[status]</td>
                       <td>$user[lastlogin]</td>
                       <td><i onclick=\"editUser($user[id],this)\" class='fa   fa-pencil-square-o' title='ویرایش اطلاعات کاربر'></i></td>
                    <td><i onclick=\"deleteUser($user[id],this)\" class='fa fa-trash-o deletUser' title='حذف کاربر' ></i></td>                    
                </tr>
            ";
            $c++;
           }
        ?>
   </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the rendered output?

Comment: second image in the question

Answer (score 1):

I can see you are using SlimTable plugin for jQuery which  creates sortable and pageable table from existing table data. After Ajax update  you have to re-applay / re-start SlimTable to reformat your content. Please  look into documentation @ https://github.com/McFizh/slimtable

```
$("#usersListTable").slimtable({
    tableData: data

 });
```

Comment: thanks . it works.$("#usersListTable").slimtable({
    tableData: null

 });